# How can I disable size-changing broadcasting when setting into a numpy array slice?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let `NoBroadcastArray` be a subclass of `np.ndarray`. If `x` is an instance of `NoBroadcastArray` and `arr` is an `np.ndarray`, then I want

```
x[slice] = arr
```

to succeed if and only if `arr.size` matches the size of slice.

```
x[1] = 1  # should succeed
x[1:2] = 1  # should fail - scalar doesn't have size 2
x[1:2] = [1,2]  # should succeed
x[1:2] = np.array([[1,2]])  # should succeed - shapes don't match but sizes do.
x[1:2, 3:4] = np.array([1,2])  # should fail - 1x2 array doesn't have same size as 2x2 array
```

In other words, an assignment should succeed if an only if the RHS doesn't have to change size to fit into the LHS slice. I don't mind if it changes shape though, e.g. if it goes from being an array of shape 1x2 to an array of being shape 2x1x1.

How can I go about achieving this? The path I'm trying now is to override __setitem__ in `NoBroadcastArray` to match the size of the slice against the size of the item to set. This is proving to be tricky, so I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea that maybe uses __array_wrap__ or __array_finalize__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the implementation that I came up with:

```
import numpy as np

class NoBroadcastArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __setitem__(self, args, value):
        value = np.asarray(value, dtype=self.dtype)
        expected_size = self._compute_expected_size(args)
        if expected_size != value.size:
            raise ValueError(("assigned value size {} does not match expected size {} "
                              "in non-broadcasting assignment".format(value.size, expected_size)))
        return super(NoBroadcastArray, self).__setitem__(args, value)

    def _compute_expected_size(self, args):
        if not isinstance(args, tuple):
            args = (args,)
        # Iterate through indexing arguments
        arr_dim = 0
        ellipsis_dim = len(args)
        i_arg = 0
        size = 1
        adv_idx_shapes = []
        for i_arg, arg in enumerate(args):
            if isinstance(arg, slice):
                size *=  self._compute_slice_size(arg, arr_dim)
                arr_dim += 1
            elif arg is Ellipsis:
                ellipsis_dim = arr_dim
                break
            elif arg is np.newaxis:
                pass
            else:
                adv_idx_shapes.append(np.shape(arg))
                arr_dim += 1
        # Go backwards from end after ellipsis if necessary
        arr_dim = -1
        for arg in args[:i_arg:-1]:
            if isinstance(arg, slice):
                size *= self._compute_slice_size(arg, arr_dim)
                arr_dim -= 1
            elif arg is Ellipsis:
                raise IndexError("an index can only have a single ellipsis ('...')")
            elif arg is np.newaxis:
                pass
            else:
                adv_idx_shapes.append(np.shape(arg))
                arr_dim -= 1
        # Include dimensions under ellipsis
        ellipsis_end_dim = arr_dim + self.ndim + 1
        if ellipsis_dim > ellipsis_end_dim:
            raise IndexError("too many indices for array")
        for i_dim in range(ellipsis_dim, ellipsis_end_dim):
            size *= self.shape[i_dim]
        size *= NoBroadcastArray._advanced_index_size(adv_idx_shapes)
        return size

    def _compute_slice_size(self, slice, axis):
        if axis >= self.ndim or axis < -self.ndim:
            raise IndexError("too many indices for array")
        size = self.shape[axis]
        start = slice.start
        stop = slice.stop
        step = slice.step if slice.step is not None else 1
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError("slice step cannot be zero")
        if start is not None:
            start = start if start >= 0 else start + size
            start = min(max(start, 0), size - 1)
        else:
            start = 0 if step > 0 else size - 1
        if stop is not None:
            stop = stop if stop >= 0 else stop + size
            stop = min(max(stop, 0), size)
        else:
            stop = size if step > 0 else -1
        slice_size = stop - start
        if step < 0:
            slice_size = -slice_size
            step = -step
        slice_size = ((slice_size - 1) // step + 1 if slice_size > 0 else 0)
        return slice_size

    @staticmethod
    def _advanced_index_size(shapes):
        size = 1
        if not shapes:
            return size
        dims = max(len(s) for s in shapes)
        for dim_sizes in zip(*(s[::-1] + (1,) * (dims - len(s)) for s in shapes)):
            d = 1
            for dim_size in dim_sizes:
                if dim_size != 1:
                    if d != 1 and dim_size != d:
                        raise IndexError("shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be "
                                         "broadcast together with shapes " + " ".join(map(str, shapes)))
                    d = dim_size
            size *= d
        return size
```

You would use it like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = NoBroadcastArray(np.arange(24).reshape(4, 3, 2, 1))

a[:] = 1
# ValueError: assigned value size 1 does not match expected size 24 in non-broadcasting assignment
a[:, ..., [0, 1], :] = 1
# ValueError: assigned value size 1 does not match expected size 16 in non-broadcasting assignment
a[[[0, 1], [2, 3]], :, [1, 0]] = 1
# ValueError: assigned value size 1 does not match expected size 12 in non-broadcasting assignment
```

This only checks that the size of the given value matches the index, but it does not do any reshaping of the value, so that still works as usual with NumPy (i.e. additional outer dimensions can be added).

Comment: Looks like this could be much trickier than I first thought. This solution seems to work so I'll mark it as accepted, but I'm curious about other possible approaches that are more concise and simple. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: @DG No problem. Feel free not to mark it as accepted if you still want to wait for other possible answers - I would also find that interesting. You make consider putting a bounty on the question if you want to attract more attention to it (two days after publication).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat shorter solution:

```
class FixedSizeSetitemArray(np.ndarray):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        value = np.asarray(value)
        current = self[index]
        if value.shape != current.shape:
            super().__setitem__(index, value)
        elif value.size == current.size:
            super().__setitem__(index, value.reshape(current.shape))
        else:
            old, new, cls = current.size, value.size, self.__class__.__name__
            raise ValueError(f"{cls} will not broadcast in __setitem__ "
                             f"(expected size {old}, got size {new})")
```

While this fits the exact requirements given, that includes arbitrarily reshaping arrays to fit the area given, which may not actually be desirable. For example, this will gladly reshape an array of shape `(2, 2, 2)` to `(8,)` or vice versa. To remove that behavior, just take out the `elif` block.

If you just want to allow extraneous dimensions to be dropped, you could use [`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).

```
elif value.squeeze().shape == current.shape:
    super().__setitem__(index, value.squeeze())
```

Some other variations on `squeeze` would allow slightly more extensive deletion of extra dimensions, but if you're running into those cases, it might be a better idea to fix the indices you are using.